# calling action with string type parameter from JavaScript in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, action

I have bellow action in my controller:

```
public ActionResult ShowContactTel(string tel)
{
    return PartialView("ContactInfoView", tel);
}
```

And I call above action by JavaScript like this: (It is fired by clicking on a button)

```
function ShowTel(){
    var e="@Model.TelShow";
    $.get("ViewProfile/ShowContactTel", e).then(
        function (r) {
            $('#divTel').innerHTML = r;
        });
}
```

But input argument of action receives null value (by setting break-point) and so return undesirable output.

Remark 1:

I tried bellow code for `ShowTel()` function but result not changed:

```
var str = "@Model.TelShow";
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Content("~/ViewProfile/ShowContactTel")',
    data: str,
    success: function (dd) {
        $('#divTel').innerHTML = dd;
    }
});
```

And

```
var str = "@Model.TelShow";
$.ajax({
    url: "ViewProfile/ShowContactTel",
    type: 'GET',
    data: str
}).then(function (r) {
    $('#divTel').innerHTML = r;
});
```

I also tried `type: 'POST'` but it not working too.

Remark 2:

Using `debugger` command in `ShowTel()` function, I see `@Model.TelShow` has true value.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code (first approach) is passing the value of `e` variable as the data parameter for the `$.get`call. jQuery `$.get` method will send that as query string values. So your code is making a get call like the below URL.

```
/ViewProfile/howContactTel?testValue
```

Assuming `testValue` is the value of variable `e`

Your action parameter name is `tel`. So send an js object with a property with that name.

Also use the jquery `html` method to update the inner html of your div.

```
$.get("/ViewProfile/ShowContactTel", { tel: e })
 .then(function (r){
       $('#divTel').html(r);
  });
```

I would also recommend using the Url helper methods to generate the correct relative URLs to the action method.

```
var url = "@Url.Action("ShowContactTel","ViewProfile");
$.get(url, { tel: e }).then(function (r){
    $('#divTel').html(r);
});
```